# Semantic Tableaux in First-Order logic: How does it work?

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm really struggling on how to resolve a Semantic Tableaux in FOL. I've read a lot of explanations but in simple I really don't understand the exact algorithm and I have not found something similar.

I know the basic rules, like instantiation of different constants for different existential quantifiers, don't eliminate universally quantified formulas and so on...

I think my problem is that I don't understand how and with which criteria the constants are substituted in the universally quantified formula.

thanks for your time

Comment: You can see the pot: [how-do-i-use-the-tableau-method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291958/how-do-i-use-the-tableau-method).

Comment: Also usefule [Truth Tress](http://www.cogsci.rpi.edu/~heuveb/teaching/Logic/CompLogic/Web/Presentations/TF-Trees.pdf).

Comment: See the post: [how-to-draw-the-tableau-of-an-inference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542610/how-to-draw-the-tableau-of-an-inference) for refernces.

Comment: Also useful the post: [confused-about-how-to-use-semantic-tableau-to-answer-questions-of-satisfiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939081/confused-about-how-to-use-semantic-tableau-to-answer-questions-of-satisfiability).

Comment: Also useful: [new-names-in-truth-trees-for-predicate-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2274226/new-names-in-truth-trees-for-predicate-logic) as well as [what-do-the-paths-of-a-truth-tree-represent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2627553/what-do-the-paths-of-a-truth-tree-represent).

Comment: I understand that anytime i drop an existential, i need to introduce a new constant but how I need to behave with the universally quantified formulas? I understand that even if they have the same name, two variable in two different clauses are different so, what should I do, substitute the constants in every possible way? Also in which order should I instantiate the universal quantifiers?

Comment: Should I first drop every existential quantifier and then instantiate all the universal ones?

Comment: Yes; a good strategy is to first instantiate all existential ones: in this way you introduce the new constants. Then use the universal quantifiers with all the new constants introduced.

Comment: So in the end, after having instantiated all the existential quantifiers I will instantiate all the possible combinations of the universally quantified formulas with the constants?

Comment: Yes; try with some simple example.

Comment: Perfect thanks this really solve my problem!